# OpsWorks Auto Healing instances that fail ELB (load balancer) test

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling, opsworks

From the AWS documentation I understand that some kind of unresponsiveness from an instance will cause it to be terminated. There is nothing in the docs that would suggest that ELB health checks can be used to mark instance as failed.

What, if anything, can be done to invoke Auto Healing when an instance fails an ELB health check ?

Thank you.

And I do know that this question is slightly rephrased [AWS Opsworks auto-healing, load instances, and load balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/568384/aws-opsworks-auto-healing-load-instances-and-load-balancer), but that one has NO answers and is 7 months old at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> Every instance has an AWS OpsWorks agent that communicates regularly with the service. AWS OpsWorks uses that communication to monitor instance health. If an agent does not communicate with the service for more than a small amount of time (approximately five minutes), AWS OpsWorks considers the instance to have failed.
>
> AWS OpsWorks automatically replaces the layer's failed instances

Hence you cannot trigger AutoHealing

The checks done by the ELB are different, they are TCP/HTTP based, for which they test connectivity to specific ports, and the action performed by the ELB is that incoming traffic is routed to healthy instances in the layer the ELB is attached to until the unhealthy instance passes the ping test done by the ELB.

Check some more details in

[AWS Opsworks auto-healing, load instances, and load balancer](https://serverfault.com/questions/568384/aws-opsworks-auto-healing-load-instances-and-load-balancer)